# how to define a struct msghdr to send UDP packet in linux kernel without copying data from user space

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I'm trying to send a Hello message from linux kernel after a UDP connect (which calls the function `ip4_datagram_connect`). Since the protocol number in this message needs to be different than UDP (This is a custom protocol which I'm building with UDP as the base code), I can't use the netpoll API.

So I'm trying to use the functions (picked up from `udp_sendmsg()`)-

```
ip_make_skb(struct sock *sk,
            struct flowi4 *fl4,
            int getfrag(void *from, char *to, int offset,
                int len, int odd, struct sk_buff *skb),
            void *from, int length, int transhdrlen,
            struct ipcm_cookie *ipc, struct rtable **rtp,
            unsigned int flags)
```

to generate the sk_buff and

```
int udp_send_skb(struct sk_buff *skb, struct flowi4 *fl4)
```

to send out the generated sk_buff.

My problem is, the function ip_make_skb requires the pointers `*from` and `length` which in the `udp_sendmsg` function are the pointer to and the length of the data in the user space(+ length of udphdr) and then `ip_make_skb()` copies the data from the userspace. Since I'm just sending a Hello message from the kernel, this is a wasteful step for me (I don't need any data from the user space).

So can I just set the `*from` pointer to some dummy location and `length` to zero(+sizeof(struct udphdr))? If yes, what kind of value for `*from` will be appropriate?

Or is this completely wrong and I should do something else?

**Edit 1:** For now, I'm doing this

```
void *from = "Hello";
```

This will give me a valid pointer in the memory, but I feel it's a dirty way to do this. Tt works though.